# Can a JSON object with 2 different data types for the same property be deserialized with the same deserialization call?

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller, deserialization

Let say I have the following 2 JSON objects that are returned from the same AJAX call depending on the parameters passed in.

The first one returns a string array for the ***child*** property:

```
{
    parent: {
        child: [
            "item 1",
            "item 2",
            "item 3",
        ]
    }
}
```

And the second one returns an object array for the ***child*** property:

```
{
    parent: {
        child: [
            {
                "attribute1": "Attribute 1",
                "attribute2": "Attribute 2",
                "attribute3": "Attribute 3"
            },
            {
                "attribute1": "Attribute 1",
                "attribute2": "Attribute 2",
                "attribute3": "Attribute 3"
            },
            {
                "attribute1": "Attribute 1",
                "attribute2": "Attribute 2",
                "attribute3": "Attribute 3"
            },
        ]
    }
}
```

Is it possible to deserialize either of these into the same model somehow? Maybe where there are 2 different properties for ***child*** (like ***ChildString*** & ***ChildObject***) that are populated accordingly depending on the type?

I'm currently using [Jil](https://github.com/kevin-montrose/Jil) for deserializing, but I'm open to others if need be.

Thanks!

Comment: see http://michaelcummings.net/mathoms/using-a-custom-jsonconverter-to-fix-bad-json-results/

Answer (score 0):

You could use a generic type for `child` and pass two different types depending on your json:

```
class Parent<T>
{
    public T child { get; set; }
}

class child
{
     string attribute1 { get; set; }
     string attribute2 { get; set; }
     string attribute3 { get; set; }
}

var parentWithList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Parent<List<string>>>(yourFirstJson);

var parentWithSingleChild = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Parent<child>(yourSecondJson);
```